# How to get a carousel at the top of a page on Plone 5

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I have tried to get a carousel working for plone 5 using the following packages:

```
collective.portlet.ngcollection
quintagroup.slidertemplates
collective.panels
```

The install all worked fine. Then in the folder in which I'd like to have a carousel at the top of the page, I tried to create a panel from the Portlets menu. This fails with the following error:

(stack snipped a bit)

```
Module five.pt.expressions, line 161, in __call__
Module plone.app.portlets.browser.manage, line 415, in render_edit_manager_portlets
Module zope.component._api, line 107, in getMultiAdapter
Module zope.component._api, line 120, in queryMultiAdapter
Module zope.component.registry, line 238, in queryMultiAdapter
Module zope.interface.adapter, line 532, in queryMultiAdapter
Module collective.panels.content, line 149, in __call__

NotImplementedError: This portlet manager does not provide a renderer.
```

This error is thrown from the:

```
collective.panel.content.PanelManager:__call__
```

method since something is clearly not sub-classing it and overriding this method.

I have followed some alternative instructions (http://quintagroup.com/services/support/tutorials/textnroll-theme/textnroll-plone5/image-carousel) which doesn't use the Panels package, but this doesn't display the carousel at the top of the page (the name does start with 'top'), but it is placed along with the other left portlets.

What else should I be doing to make this work? I have installed Plone 5.0 (5011) running on ubuntu 14.04.

Many thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using an (or more) add-on not Plone 5 compatible.

You said you found a compatible ones but it's not in the position you like: remember that you are on Plone 5 and you have [Diazo](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.theming/docs/) under the hood.

When using Diazo you don't need anymore to think about where an add-on will display something but you, through theme's rules, can move elements in the proper position.

Final though: when you have Diazo a lot of UI add-ons like carousel, sliders, can be skipped completely if you don't need to manage them from the CMS.
Just find a carousel you like and integrate it in the theme.

Comment: Luca - thanks for your reply. You are right, it's probably easier to start from the diazo rules, include a JS-only carousel on the home page that refers to images in a folder. I'd just hoped that could be as easy as include an add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used any of the packages that you have used, but I am using
[collective.behavior.banner](https://github.com/collective/collective.behavior.banner). It worked for me easily.
The installation instructions are clear in the link but I have mentioned them for reference.

Make sure to make the following changes to the buildout.cfg.

- Include the collective.behavior.banner in the eggs.

eggs= ...

```
  collective.behavior.banner
```

- Include the right version in the [versions] section ( Include the one that is compatible with Plone 5 ). I have tested for version - 1.0b1

[versions]

...

collective.behavior.banner= 1.0b1

...

- Go to Site-Setup -> Add-ons: Install the add-on which will appear in
  the list.
- Go to Site-Setup -> Dexterity Content Types -> Page ->
  Behaviors: Select Banner and Slider behavior. (Remember that the add-on is a behavior add-on).
- Exit Site Setup to the Main Pages.
- Add a new Folder called "Banners" for example and add as many pages in it as there are in your carousel.
- Edit all the pages that you have added and select Banner (Which will be visible after adding the Add-On)
- Upload Images, give titles wherever necessary, make changes according to your needs, and Save.
- Now go to the page on which you have to add the Carousel/Slider.
- Edit it -> select Slider: Select all the banners added in the "Banners" Folder. Set titles wherever necessary. And it is done!!

Comment: Many thanks for adding your solution to this question. This package looks excellent - the ability to have richer content in the banner will be great. I will try it out!

Comment: Glad that I could be of any help!!